# string_agg () is not working for Postgres sql when joining on multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, string-agg

I have to join user_name from user table where as first_name and last_names from user_profile table. Until here everything is fine, but when I try to fetch respective roles assigned from user_role tables it gives multiple rows for single user as 1 user can have multiple roles.

While trying to apply `string_agg` on role.names (so that multiple roles shown comma separated in single tuple), it gives each role in separate row.

Here is example query I am trying to run in postgresql:

```
 SELECT users.user_name, user_profiles.first_name, user_profiles.last_name,
(
    SELECT string_agg (roles.name, ',') 
    from roles 
    where roles.id in (
        select user_roles.role_id where users.id = user_roles.user_id
    )
) as name
FROM users 
JOIN user_profiles ON users.id = user_profiles.user_id
JOIN user_roles    ON user_roles.user_id = users.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `GROUP BY` clause in order to aggregate more than one record together within a group. That along with the unnecessary (I believe) nested SQL is leading you to wrong results.

Instead consider the following:

```sql
    SELECT users.user_name, user_profiles.first_name, user_profiles.last_name,
        string_agg (roles.name, ',') as name
    FROM users 
      JOIN user_profiles 
        ON users.id = user_profiles.user_id
      JOIN user_roles
        ON user_roles.user_id = users.id
      JOIN roles ON user_roles.role_id = roles.id
    GROUP BY users.user_name, user_profiles.first_name, user_profiles.last_name
```

[Online demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vzXtpAgq9YZp2ki1Tw5ivT/0)

Comment: In Postgres, `GROUP BY users.id` is sufficient here, since that's the PK of the users table.

Comment: While I agree with the recommendation, both points in this answer are incorrect. @GMB I don't follow. It would throw `error: column "user_profiles.first_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function` for each selected field outside aggregate functions.

Comment: while things are moving on, I am now struggling with having user_profiles table not mendatory.      fetch user_profiles.first_name, user_profiles.last_name from user_profiles but if no data found show the results of respective user_id.     ---- right now query dont show those user which has presence in user table but no respective data in profile table.

Comment: got it solved by removing join for user_profiles and fetching profiles via inner query              `SELECT users.id as user_id, users.is_active ,  roles.name as role_name, roles.id as role_id, 
( SELECT user_profiles.first_name from user_profiles where user_profiles.user_id = users.id) as name
FROM ums_users
 
  JOIN ums_user_roles
    ON ums_user_roles.user_id = ums_users.id`.....

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a `from` in your innermost subquery:

```sql
SELECT  users.user_name, 
        user_profiles.first_name, 
        user_profiles.last_name,
        (SELECT string_agg (roles.name, ', ') 
         from  roles 
         where roles.id 
         in (   select u.role_id 
                from user_roles u --this was missing
                where users.id = u.user_id)) as name
FROM users 
    JOIN user_profiles 
        ON users.id = user_profiles.user_id
--  JOIN user_roles --you're already getting roles in the innermost query
--      ON user_roles.user_id = users.id;
```

without it, that subquery was just selecting one, current row's `role_id`, instead independently fetching of all roles for the user as you could've expected it to. See this [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vzXtpAgq9YZp2ki1Tw5ivT/2).

Note that once this is fixed, you also need to get rid of the last join (commented out in my example) to avoid multiplying users for each of their roles - you're already getting their roles in the innermost subquery anyways.

It would be easier to use a regular [`group by`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-agg.html):

```sql
select  users.user_name, 
        user_profiles.first_name, 
        user_profiles.last_name,
        string_agg(roles.name,', ')
from users 
    inner join user_profiles 
        on users.id=user_profiles.user_id
    inner join user_roles 
        on user_roles.user_id=users.id
    inner join roles 
        on roles.id=user_roles.role_id
group by 1,2,3;
```